# Deducing inequality of proof of existence of ode.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

Let $x'=f(x)$ $x(0)=x_0$ assuming that $|f(x)-f(x)|\le L|x-y|$. We have $x(t)=x_0+\displaystyle\int_0^tf(t)dt$.

Let's say $$x_{n+1}=x_0+\int_0^tf(x_n(t))dt$$ and $$|x_{n+1}-x_n(t)|\le L\int_0^t|x_{n}(t)-x_{n-1}(t)|dt.$$ Deduce that $\max_{t\in[0,0.5L]}|x_{n+1}-x_n(t)|\le0.5\max_{t\in[0,0.5L]}|x_{n}(t)-x_{n-1}(t)|$.

I can't deduce this problem. I have tried using MVT but it only shows that $$|x_{n}(t)-x_{n-1}(t)|\le L\int_0^t|x_{n}(t)-x_{n-1}(t)|dt.$$ How to deduce that inequality?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean $t\in[0,0.5/L]$? With $d_n(a)=\max_{s\in[0,a]}|x_n(s)-x_{n-1}(s)|$ and $t\in[0,a]$ you get from your last inequality
$$
|x_{n+1}(t)-x_n(t)|\le L\int_0^td_n(a)\,ds=Ld_n(a)t\le La\,d_n(t)
$$
so that also
$$
d_{n+1}(a)\le La\,d_n(a)
$$
and you want $La=\frac12$ to get controlled contractivity.

---

Note that if you take $d_n(a)=\max_{s\in[0,a]}e^{-2Ls}|x_n(s)-x_{n-1}(s)|$, then you get $d_{n+1}(a)\le\frac12d_n(a)$ independent of $a$.